# Create a File Explorer in winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which contains a Combobox, a Tree View and a listview.

I want to populate the drives of the system in the combobox and the fokders inside it into the treeview and the files into listview.

I am totally new to this thing so I seriously need some help on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sounds like you have developed Visual Basic 6 before. Today you'd use a FileOpenDialog provided by the operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at this site were Microsoft provids a Walkthrough for creating an Explorer Style Interface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171645.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a file use `OpenFileDialog`. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want to save a file use `SaveFileDialog`. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

`OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialg` can be used either by checking the `DialogResult` or by handling `FileOk` event but the first option allows you to handle operations like user canceling file open/save.

If you want to select a directory use `FolderBrowserDialog`. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you really need to create a custom tree you could use the following:

- [DriveInfo.GetDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It would be great if you can help me with some sample code.
I am not sure how to add folders to the treeview.